# Jetpack Compose Google maps button customization

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I am using new library for jetpack compose google maps
`implementation "com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:1.0.0"`
and trying to customize my button, I want to change it`s position and icon.

This is my code with initialization of GoogleMap()

```
@Composable
private fun GoogleMapView(hasPermission: Boolean, modifier: Modifier, onMapLoaded: () -> Unit) {
    val defaultCamera = LatLng(42.6977, 23.3219)
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(defaultCamera, 11f)
    }

    var properties by remember { mutableStateOf(MapProperties(isMyLocationEnabled = hasPermission)) }
    var uiSettings by remember { mutableStateOf(MapUiSettings(zoomControlsEnabled = false)) }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager


    GoogleMap(
        modifier = modifier,
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        properties = properties,
        uiSettings = uiSettings,
        onMapLoaded = onMapLoaded,
        googleMapOptionsFactory = {
            GoogleMapOptions().camera(CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(defaultCamera, 11f))
        },
        onMyLocationButtonClick = {

            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            ) {
                buildAlertMessageNoGps(context)
                return@GoogleMap true
            }
            return@GoogleMap false
        }
    )

}
```

And this is my custom button I want to implement. With older way I just give as argument mapView, but here i don`t know how to get it.

```
private fun setupMyLocationButton(mapView: com.google.android.libraries.maps.MapView) {
    val buttonName = "GoogleMapMyLocationButton"
    val locationButton: ImageView =
        mapView.findViewWithTag(buttonName)
    locationButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_btn)

    val rlp = locationButton.layoutParams as? (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)

    rlp?.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0)
    rlp?.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE)
    rlp?.setMargins(
        0, 0, 30, 30
    )
}
```

Official documentation -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with the Maps Compose library. I suggest filing a feature request for it here: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%3A+feature+request%2C+triage+me&template=feature_request.md&title=